# Best pratice for Child Class logging in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, logging

I'd like to get your ideas of how to implement nice code for parent- and child- classes that needs to logged.

My problem is that I need to log parent and child instance attributes at creation, means inside **init**-function.
Creating a child instance causes also its parent class to log a message. Is it possible to only log a message from parent-instance when not called from a child-instance?

That's a simple example of my problem, thanks in advance ...

```
import logging
from uuid import uuid4

logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)s %(levelname)-7s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("here")


class A:
    init_log_message = "Instance of P"
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid4()
#        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.error(f"{A.init_log_message}")


class B(A):
    init_log_message = "Instance of C"
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid4()
        super().__init__()
#        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning(f"{B.init_log_message}")


b = B()
```

Console output as follows:

```
__main__ DEBUG  :here
__main__ ERROR  :Instance of P
__main__ WARNING:Instance of C
```

The message in the midlle come from the parent classe via super() command I assume. How can this message be avoided?

Thanks for any idea or comment ...

Comment: It seems you changed your question. What do you want to do with `uuid4`? Also, if you call `super().__init__()`, you are executing all the code of `A.__init__()`. You can access static attributes with `self`.

Comment: The uuid4 is used to mark an instance by an id and this way nicely show the relationship between child/parent calls as the share the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `init_log_message` static string on your `Parent` class and override it in your `Child` class:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Parent:
    init_log_message = "Instance P created"

    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug(self.init_log_message)

class Child(Parent):
    init_log_message = "Instance C created"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")
    p = Parent()
    c = Child()
```

Note that `logger` is no longer a class attribute, as both `Parent.logger` and `Child.logger` were the same in your example code, so I migrated it as a module attribute.

Comment: Hello Neraste, I tried it but the behaviour is the same as before.

Comment: I added an execution block. Running the code would give the expected result for your question before you edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found some way to log only child-instance without any logging reaction of their parent-instance.

I put these lines into the **init**-functions to only log when no child exists.

```
def __init__(self):
    if not SensorBase.__subclasses__():
            logger.debug(f"<{__class__.__name__} Instance created: "
                         f"UUID={self.id}, NAME={self.name}@{self.node}>")
```